# Não consigo achar o motivo para meu código não fazer o calculo corretamente

Tags: c

Estou começando a programar agora e para aprender coisas novas estou tentando fazer um código em C que calcule se o usuário recebe mais ou menos de 3 salários mínimos.  Porem ao fazer a soma dos 4 últimos salários do usuário o resultado é incoerente com os valores digitados.

Aqui está o código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int A = 998; //Salario minimo
    float X, Y, Z, K; //Armazena os 4 ultimos salarios
    int C = A * 3; //Calcula quanto equivale 3 salarios minimos
    float D = X+Y+Z+K; //Soma os 4 ultimos salarios

    printf("Digite seus 4 ultimos salarios, 1º");
    scanf("%f", &X);

    printf("2º");
    scanf("%f", &Y);

    printf("3º");
    scanf("%f", &Z);

    printf("4º");
    scanf("%f", &K);

    printf("A soma dos salarios é: %f", D);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Imagem da execução do código]

Espero que possam me ajudar.

Comment: Você calculou o valor de `D` antes de ler os valores de `X`, `Y`, `Z` e `K`?

Comment: Acho que foi isso, conseguir agora que botei a variável para calcular o valor de D depois da leitura dos valores. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calcule o valor de `C` após ter capturando o valor de X, Y, Z e K, veja abaixo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int A = 998; //Salario minimo
    float X, Y, Z, K; //Armazena os 4 ultimos salarios
    int C = A * 3; //Calcula quanto equivale 3 salarios minimos

    printf("Digite seus 4 ultimos salarios, 1º");
    scanf("%f", &X);

    printf("2º");
    scanf("%f", &Y);

    printf("3º");
    scanf("%f", &Z);

    printf("4º");
    scanf("%f", &K);

    float D = X+Y+Z+K; //Soma os 4 ultimos salarios

    printf("A soma dos salarios é: %f", D);

    return 0;
}
```